# Grow mdadm raid from raid1 to raid0 with active lvm

Tags: raid, lvm, software-raid

We rented a server with two NVMe disks in a raid1 configuration with a lvm on top of that.

Is it possible to change the raid level to raid0 without making any changes to the lvm config? We don't need redundancy but might need more disk space soon.

I have no experience with mdadm. I tried running `mdadm --grow /dev/md4 -l 0` but got an error: `mdadm: failed to remove internal bitmap.`

Some additional info:

The OS is `ubuntu 18.04`
The hosting provider is `IONOS`
I have access to a debian rescue system but no physical access to the server.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md4
=======================

/dev/md4:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Wed May 12 09:52:01 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 898628416 (857.00 GiB 920.20 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 898628416 (857.00 GiB 920.20 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed May 12 10:55:07 2021
             State : clean, degraded, recovering 
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 7% complete

              Name : punix:4
              UUID : 42d57123:263dd789:ef368ee1:8e9bbe3f
            Events : 991

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        9        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p4
       2     259        4        1      spare rebuilding   /dev/nvme1n1p4


/proc/mdstat:
=======

Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0] nvme1n1p2[2]
      29293440 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
        resync=DELAYED
      
md4 : active raid1 nvme0n1p4[0] nvme1n1p4[2]
      898628416 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [U_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.8% (25617280/898628416) finish=704.2min speed=20658K/sec
      bitmap: 1/7 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>


df -h:
======

Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  6.3G   11M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md2                28G  823M   27G   3% /
/dev/vg00/usr          9.8G 1013M  8.3G  11% /usr
tmpfs                   32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg00-home  9.8G   37M  9.3G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   9.8G  348M  9.0G   4% /var
tmpfs                  6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0


fdisk -l:
=========

Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 894.3 GiB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3FEDFA8D-D63F-42EE-86C9-5E728FA617D2

Device            Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1     2048       6143       4096    2M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme1n1p2     6144   58593279   58587136   28G Linux RAID
/dev/nvme1n1p3 58593280   78125055   19531776  9.3G Linux swap
/dev/nvme1n1p4 78125056 1875382271 1797257216  857G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/md4: 857 GiB, 920195497984 bytes, 1797256832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 28 GiB, 29996482560 bytes, 58586880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 894.3 GiB, 960197124096 bytes, 1875385008 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 948B7F9A-0758-4B01-8CD2-BDB08D0BE645

Device            Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1     2048       6143       4096    2M BIOS boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2     6144   58593279   58587136   28G Linux RAID
/dev/nvme0n1p3 58593280   78125055   19531776  9.3G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p4 78125056 1875382271 1797257216  857G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


lvm configuration:
==================

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md4
  VG Name               vg00
  PV Size               <857.00 GiB / not usable 2.81 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              219391
  Free PE               211711
  Allocated PE          7680
  PV UUID               bdTpM6-vxql-momc-sTZC-0B3R-VFtZ-S72u7V
   
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg00
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <857.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              219391
  Alloc PE / Size       7680 / 30.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       211711 / <827.00 GiB
  VG UUID               HIO5xT-VRw3-BZN7-3h3m-MGqr-UwOS-WxOQTS
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/usr
  LV Name                usr
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                cv3qcf-8ZB4-JaIp-QYvo-x4ol-veIH-xI37Z6
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time punix, 2021-05-12 09:52:03 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/var
  LV Name                var
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                ZtAM8T-MO4F-YrqF-hgUN-ctMC-1RSn-crup3E
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time punix, 2021-05-12 09:52:03 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg00/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                vg00
  LV UUID                AeIwpS-dnX1-6oGP-ieZ2-hmGs-57zd-6DnXRv
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time punix, 2021-05-12 09:52:03 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.00 GiB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

Thanks

Comment: The error of not being able to remove the bitmap is probably temporary because one disk is rebuilding as per your mdstat output. After that recovery is finished you could proceed. Or you can just "fail" and "remove" the nvme1 drive from your arrays and then grow to raid0 and add the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the approach you were originally considering, but you could move LVM data between disks so you end up with both drives as LVM physical volumes in your volume group.

To do that, you would remove one drive from the RAID1 array, run `pvcreate` on the detached drive to reformat it, then add it your LVM volume with `vgextend`. This should double your LVM volume group size. Then remove the degraded array from the LVM VG, which should transfer data in a way that is fairly fault tolerant. (See the the "NOTES" section in the `pvmove` man page for details). Once that degraded array has been removed from your VG, you can stop the array, then add the remaining drive to the LVM group the same way you added the other drive.

I recently migrated LVM hosted data in a similar scenario, but from a RAID10 with two copies of data, to two RAID1 arrays with three copies per array, and with larger disks. So we got the best of both worlds: more data, and more reliability. I don't know what your use case is, but I should mention that I personally wouldn't feel comfortable hosting data without RAID unless it's easy to re-generate from scratch. 2 TB seems like a lot of data to recreate or sync, but if no one would be bothered by extended downtime or the network traffic, it's your call.

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawlessly. I had to use `wipefs -a` before running `pvcreate`, which seemd a little brute-force, but worked fine.

Comment: The servers basically just serve static files that are easy to sync. Therefore we decided against a raid. For now it has never been a problem and a downtime would be fine as we has multiple servers doing the same job.